# How to update location in for http call

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, reverse-proxy, node-http-proxy

Im using the reverse proxy from the following link,
currently Im getting some location and I want to update it(the location),
How can I do that?

```
proxy.on('proxyRes', function (proxyRes, req, res) {

res.headers.location = 'http:/a/b/'

});
```

and I need to change it for example to be

res.headers.location = 'http:/c/d/'
I will handle the logic how to change the URL but I want to know how to update it...

https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

Comment: Do you want to redirect the web browser to another URL, is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

in order to change the location headers try using **res.location()**

```
proxy.on('proxyRes', function (proxyRes, req, res) {

 res.location('http:/c/d/');

});
```

`res.location` just sets the response header. It does not set a response status code or close the response, so you can write a response body it you want, and you have to call `res.end()` on your own after.

**Reference**:  [Express Location](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.location) , [the source](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/response.js)

Hope this helps.